# Get Rid Of the Word FALSE When A Cell I Empty

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get rid a empty cell with the word FALSE

```
=IF(OR(A3="YES",),"DVR GOOD ", IF(OR(A3="NO",),"BAD SITE"))
```

Comment: ```IF(OR(A3="NO",),"BAD SITE", "Put something in the else bit!"))```?

Comment: What the heck is `OR(A3="YES",)`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this formula was built, but it is mostly nonsense, especially the ORs are completely useless. What you should use is this:

```
=IF(A3="YES","DVR GOOD",IF(A3="NO","BAD SITE","write here what you want to see instead of FALSE"))
```